# Document scanning software with OCR that takes advantage of multiple CPUs

Tags: windows, ocr, scanning

At the moment I use the software that came with my CanoScan flatbed scanners. My major complaint about the bundled software: no possibility to define scan profiles, too slow (not capable of using multiple CPU cores/threads).

What I look for is not for batch processing with higher-volume ADF document scanners but for ad hoc capture with flatbed scanners. It is for scanning documents not suitable for ADF scanners, i.e. documents that are too thin/thick/large or that consist of several smaller pieces that need to be together on one image.

I imagine a workflow comparable to that on enterprise MFPs where you place your document on the glass and choose a scan profile on the display, except that you choose the scan profile on the PC to which the flatbed scanner is attached.

Envisaged software features:

1. works with TWAIN drivers,
2. scan profiles (= user defined combination of dpi, image enhancement settings, OCR language, output file type),
3. optimized for multiple CPU cores/threads,
4. image enhancement features (selectable as part of scan profiles) e.g. descreen, prevent bleed through, deskew, auto-crop,
5. OCR for the major European languages,
6. output format: TIFF, searchable PDF, PDF/A, jpg, jpg2000

I would like to avoid a software that follows the batch scanning approach because it adds unnecessary complexity.

I run Windows, but I am considering to move to Mac OS as an alternative if I don't find some suitable Windows software and there is a good software for OSX.

Comment: Worth a look then: [Tool for extracting text from a scan](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/851/185). Not exactly what you're after, but see the *OCRFeeder* answer: that tool directly supports scanners (one page per scan), and should fulfill at least points d to f of your list. Not being a Windows user, I have no direct recommendation for that platform.

Comment: It looks like you want faster software. Would you accept a single threaded solution if it performed noticeably faster?

Comment: @Kelly Thomas: Yes, I would.

Answer (score 1):

I add Vuescan by hamrick.com to my suggestion list.

I suggest Omnipage Pro by Nuance.

It supports 120 languages.

http://www.nuance.com/for-business/by-product/omnipage/ultimate/index.htm

As far as scanning profiles my epson scanner software does have them.  So "scan profiles" could be missing depending on your scanner.

**Scanning programs love memory, you need at least 8GB if not 16GB**

Loading support
[image]
Saving Image type:
[image]
Saving text type:
[image]
Here is image enhancing toolbar
[image]
From left to right
"Pointer" "Zoom" "Select Area" "Switch between primary and OCR image" "Syncronize views" "Brightness/Contrast" "Hue/Saturation/Ligthness" "Crop" "Rotate/Flip" "Despeckle" "OCR brightness" "Drop-out Color" "Resolution" "Deskew" "3d Deskew" "Fill" "AutoCrop" "Clean borders" "Punch hole remover" "Enhanced Whiteboard Photo"

Comment: Many thanks for your hint! The software is quite pricy at 500 USD. From the list of features at the link you provided, it is not clear whether my criteria 2., 3, 4., and 6. are met. Omnipage is on the market for a long time. Such legacy software is often overloaded with unnecessary features and awful to use. Is it userfriendly so that you don't need to spend hours to figure out how to use it?

Comment: I suggest you call/email/etc and get a trial version of Omnipage Pro Ultimate.  Adobe acrobat Pro is similar but equally expensive.

Comment: In terms of user-friendly all normal features are.  There are advanced features you make have to learn.  I have not tested the newest version of every software, but this product was at the time of testing better than any other software than came with a scanner, except Adobe Pro was too expensive so I have not tested it.  I have used version I and friends/family/etc have.  Features like scanning a page with 3 columns and one or more have a picture, or the picture cuts across 3 columns usually causes most other scanning products to barf.  Omnipage clearly does a better job.

Comment: cybernard said ""scan profiles" could be missing depending on your scanner". As you say, scan profiles can be a part of your TWAIN/ISIS driver. But there is also scan software on the market with scan profiles independent of the scanner driver (e.g. ExactScan for Mac). Scan profiles allow to automate scanning a lot. The functions you show in the screen shot "Image Enhancement" are manual ones, which is contrary to my aim of automation.

Comment: Adobe has 5 predefined scan profiles, one of it is "Custom Scan...". What I need is the possibility to define my own profiles - not only one but let's say at least 10. Omnipage Pro Ultimate apparently does not support that features. So, it is not suitable for my purpose.

Comment: My scanner driver offers scan profiles. Since a scanner driver never includes OCR, I need to devide the document capture into 2 steps: 1st scanning, 2nd OCR. What I am looking for is to have these 2 steps in one go. Then a user could open the scan software, choose a profile according to the features of the document to be scanned and gets the result without knowing much about the details of the software. ExactScan does that for Mac. There is a beta of ExactScan for Windows but it is not optimized for multiple CPU cores/threads.

Comment: If you set Omnipage Pro up to use TWAIN drivers for the scanner it will display the native scanner interface.  I tried to use ExactScan for windows and it could not recognize my scanner and when I tried to save a PDF with searchable text I got no text when I used an image file as a substitute for a scanner.

Comment: Now that I have know how ExactScan works I would definately recommend Vuescan from www.hamrick.com.  Free demo available.  Options are saveable to .ini files so you can load multiple profiles easily.  You will have to click the advanced button on several different screens to enable OCR and save the text to a file if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on ExactScan beta. 
The native scanner interface is often (as an option) accessible in scan software, e.g. also in Adobe. The problem is that it usually requires additonal clicks to get there - sometimes too many (as in Adobe). Such as solution is one the one hand not "idiot-proof" and on the other hand unnecessarily adds clicks and time to get a result. I think some scanner producers move into this direction with scan profiles (e.g. Canon) but their are not fully there yet (Canon software e.g. lacks the possibility to configure your own scan profiles).

Comment: I know Vuescan and like it. Unfortunately, it works only with WIA but not with TWAIN drivers. And one of my scanners has a WIA driver that is unusable because of a bug. It's a pity that I cannot use Vuescan with this scanner.

Comment: Some time ago I tested IDM Scan 2.0 (www.idmscan.com). It offers scan profiles. I didn't have enough time to fully test it before the trial period run out. If I remember correctly it does not offer OCR and I was not fully convinced by the user interface.

Comment: Have you emailed the author of Vuescan to see if they would add TWAIN support for your scanner?  Can I assume your periodically check for driver updates and/or emailed the company to see if scanner w/broken WIA will be fixed?  You might be better off scanning everything as 600/1200 dpi TIFF and OCR them afterwards.  A new scanner compatible via TWAIN and Vuescan would cost way less than professional grade software.  Epson v550 is $149 and compatible with VueScan.

Comment: Yes, I contacted Vuescan. It does not use TWAIN, only WIA. Unfortunately, Lexmark did not update the WIA driver since more than 2 years. I contacted them now and will see what they say.

Comment: The problem with flatbed scanners is the rather slow speed. The Lexmark Genesis S815 uses a camera module that shoots a picture of the whole page. Scanning is done in 3 seconds. Most standard flatbed scanners need 8 seconds or more. My idea was to automate the process as much as possible in one step with a quick capture by the scanner. 
I am surpised that no other manufacturer offers a flatbed scanner with camera module. The advantage of higher speed is quite obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Abbyy Finereader](http://finereader.abbyy.com/), honnestly, I'm not sure it meets all your criteria because I used and older version a few years ago. All I remember is it worked with my scanner and was really efficient and easy to use.

Anyway, you can try it for free so the best way to find if it really suits your needs is give it a try I think.

Edit : According to the [technical specifications of the latest vesrion](http://finereader.abbyy.com/professional/tech_specs/) it seems to meet your expectations pretty well.

Comment: I know Abbyy Finereader. It's focus is on OCR not on scan automation in my sense. Because it does not offer scan profiles, it is dead in the water.